# Flash Cross Domain Policy for Apache

Tags: flash, apache

I was looking around but couldn't find it where can I add the cross domain policy of Adobe in Apache server. Because without it, its not letting me access my XML on another server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just placed it on the root and told apache to treat it seperatly worked :D